# click() does perform a click but ends with an error

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I have a button on a dialog box which when it is clicked, pops up a confirm popup window.

Whenever I perform a click on that button using pywinauto, the click does occur in the UI, however the click() function does not return without throwing this error:

```
COMError: (-2147220991, 'An event was unable to invoke any of the subscribers', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

The code to click the button is very simple:

```py
readerDlg = mainDlg.window(title=READER_WINDOW_TITLE)
readerDlg.Skip.click()
```

Connection snippet:

```py
sw = Application(backend='uia').connect(title=APPLICATION_TITLE)
mainDlg = sw.window(title=MAIN_WINDOW_TITLE)
```

Comment: Looks like this is a [common known issue](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/563), what research have you done so far?

Comment: I had a look at that and [#621](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/621) but they seem to use `click_input()` and `double_click_input()` as a workaround which is not something I can use because I need to keep mouse control with myself at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching the backend from `uia` to `win32` fixed my issue:

```py
sw = Application(backend='win32').connect(title=APPLICATION_TITLE)
```

It also made the automation much faster (from ~5 sec/op to < 1 sec/op.